# How to change class on several divs using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs:

```
    <div class="gif_left">
    <div class="gif_right">
```

Initially, the first one has opacity 1, and the second one has opacity 0.

I want onclick function on `.gif_left` and change its class on `.click`:

`.click { opacity: 0; }`

And I also want that at the same onclick function change class `.gif_right` on:

`.click2 { opacity: 1; }`

When I click again, everything returns as it was.

Now I have only been able to assign onclick function to `.gif_left` and change its class to .click (it also works when you click again by toggleClass):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gif_left').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('click');
  });
});
```

Comment: _"Initially, the first one has opacity 1, and the second one has opacity 0."_ How do you set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think the easiest way to do this is to use jQuery to find the elements you want and toggle them both in the same handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gif_left').click(function () {
    $('.gif_left').toggleClass('click');
    $('.gif_right').toggleClass('click2');
  });
});
```

That is, instead of using `$(this)`, use a jQuery selector to find the element. If you do this on a very large complex page, you may need to optimise it, but for a simple example it should work fine.

If you want to have click handlers on both divs, you can use [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.gif_left, .gif_right').click(function () {
    $('.gif_left').toggleClass('click');
    $('.gif_right').toggleClass('click2');
  });
});
```

Pro-tip: if you're using opacity to dynamically turn things on/off, you may want to also add a CSS transition to animate the effect. For a two-second transition, just update your CSS for `.click` and `.click2` to add `transition: opacity 2s;`.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. What do I need if I want to add several .click functions?

Comment: I've added an example with using multiple selectors with jQuery. You can also just duplicate the middle four lines. Could you please accept the answer if it helped solve your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to run the code snippet below. I manipulated their background color to make it more obvious. Feel free to use the CSS attributes that you want.

```js
$('.mydiv').on('click', function(){

$('.gif_left').toggleClass("click click2");
$('.gif_right').toggleClass("click2 click");

})
```

```css
.click { background-color: red; }
.click2 { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gif_left click mydiv"><br/><br/>gif_left<br/></div>

<div class="gif_right click2 mydiv"><br/><br/>gif_right<br/></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't use the div's onclick, but instead uses a button.

Comment: @tresf - updated answer, it now uses div's click.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which toggles the `transparency` as requested, resetting when clicked again.

1. It uses a jQuery CSS matching on any div named `gif_*` so that the `onclick` listener is added to both divs.
2. It re-uses the `toggleClass` function to toggle the `transparency` on and off, but cycling over all divs to ensure that all matching divs are toggled.
3. Uses a class called `off` so that a quick inspection of the HTML can see which `div` is turned off.
4. Basic CSS added for display purposes only, marked as such.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gif_left">left</div>
<div class="gif_right off">right</div>

<style>
    div.off {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    /* display purposes only */
    div {
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 16pt;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
    div.gif_left {
        background-color: red;
    }
    div.gif_right {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var gifs = $('div[class^="gif_"]');
    gifs.click(() => {
        gifs.each((index, elem) => {
            $(elem).toggleClass("off");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Note:

- `click2` has been removed from this example for simplicity because the default opacity of an element is already `1`.
- `click` has been renamed to `off` for clarity.

As a slight aside, the resulting UI behaves a lot like a radiobutton, and for that reason it may make sense to instead prefer a solution which re-usse the radiobutton with a custom style, if the similarity is correct and intended.